# Construction of one complex from given two (in non-direct-sum manner): is it motivated by topology?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

The following exercise appears in Basic Algebra 2 by Jacobson. My question a little philosophical.

> Let $\alpha$ be a homomorphism of the chain complex $(C,d))$ into the chain complex $(C',d')$. Define $C_i''=C_{i-1}\oplus C_i'$, $i\in\mathbb{Z}$, and if $x_{i-1}\in C_{i-1}$, $x_i'\in C_i'$, then define $d_i''(x_{i-1}, x_i')=(-d_{i-1}x_{i-1}, \alpha_{i-1}x_{i-1}+d_i'x_i')$. Verify that $(C'',d'')$ is a complex.

I proved that this is a complex.

But after looking book of Hatcher and Massey on Algebraic Topology, I did not see in what context such sequences appear in Algebraic Topology.

Since the Beginning Homological Algebra include those topics, whose origin lies highly in Algebraic Topology, including the adaption of some terminologies: chain, cochain, cocycle, cycle, boundary, homology, etc.

Therefore, I wondered whether construction of the third complex in Exercise from two complexes (in a not necessarily direct-sum manner) is motivated from topology? Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've described is the *mapping cone* of the chain map $\alpha,$ and is denoted by $\mathrm{cone}(\alpha)$. As you suspect, this construction is analogous to the similarly named construction in topology. The mapping cone of a map of simplicial complexes $f:X\to Y$ is the space obtained by considering $\left(X\times [0,1]\right)\cup Y$ collapsing $X\times \{0\}$ to a point, and identifying each $(x,1)$ with $f(x)\in Y.$ We denote this space by $\mathrm{cone}(f).$ If we let $C(X)$ and $C(Y)$ denote the complexes of singular chains in $X$ and $Y$ respectively then $\mathrm{cone}(f_*)$ (the mapping cone of the map of chain complexes $f_*:C(X)\to C(Y)$) is isomorphic after a small modification in degree $0$ to $C(\mathrm{cone}(f)),$ that is, the complex of singular chains of the simplicial complex $\mathrm{cone}(f).$